# Variable initialization issue in switch statement

Tags: c#, .net, language-agnostic, switch-statement

What I have is simple switch statement

```
Control myControl;
switch(x)
{
     case TabType.Edit:
     {
         myControl= ...;
     }

     case TabType.View:
     {

         myControl= ...;
     }
 }

 myPageView.Controls.Add(myControl);
```

In this situation compiler tells me that

> local variable myControl might not be initialized before accessing

**So, what is the best way to avoid this situation?**

One option is to initialize myControl before switch statement. But in this case I do one more unnecessary initalization.

*CASE 1:*

```
Control myControl = null;
switch(x)
{
     case TabType.Edit:
     {
         myControl= ...;
     }

     case TabType.View:
     {

         myControl= ...;
     }
 }

 myPageView.Controls.Add(myControl);
```

Next option is to change second case with `default`. After that compiler will "understand" that myControl will be anyway initialized and will not throw exception.

*CASE 2:*

```
Control myControl;
switch(x)
{
     case TabType.Edit:
     {
         myControl= ...;
     }

     default:
     {

         myControl= ...;
     }
 }

 myPageView.Controls.Add(myControl);
```

But this case doesn't look so good, because after adding some new properties to my enum it will do default for all other types(developer can easily forget to change code here or it can be not necessary to initialize myControl for other enum types).

What is best approach in such situations?

Comment: The compiler give you the answer .. just set it to null local your error "variable myControl might not be initialized before accessing"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code sample indicates that you will always make use of the `myControl` variable after the switch block.  If that's the case, then you should either pre-initialize the variable, or add a `default` clause (as you mentioned).

If you are concerned that a new enumerated value might be introduced, then you could throw a meaningful exception in the `default` clause.  That would safeguard you from getting a more ambiguous `NullReferenceException` when you try to dereference the variable later.

Comment: +1 for throwing an exception when `default` case is hit. Also a good alternative.

Comment: Thanks to everyone :) Default clause with throwing meaningful exception is nice approach.

Comment: Chuck Norris can safely deference a Null Reference without getting a NullReferenceException

Answer (score 3):

Third option: Validate an instance was created before proceeding (instead of relying on it being assigned):

```
Control mycontrol = null;
switch (x){
  // ...
}
if (myControl != null){
  // add to controls list, manipulate, etc.
}
```

You could also add `default:` fall-through case to the `default(TabType)` value:

```
switch (x){
  case TabType.Two:
    // ...
  case TabType.Three:
    // ...
  case TabType.One:
  default:
    // ..
}
```

Comment: Your second case was his second case.

Comment: @ServyL yes, but I've made it an explicit declaration instead of exempting the `default(Tabtype)` value and just using `default:`.

Comment: @DJKRAZE: one of those weeks where the fingers have had very little reprieve; They seem to be boycotting typing ATM. ;p

Comment: Brad's example goes deeper than the OP's original 2nd example and is more readable as well as a good way to properly do a Switch{ case} statement.. great example Brad

Answer (score 2):

I think that `default` exists specifically for these situations.

*adding some new properties to my enum it will do default for all other types*

It will allow your code to work on default premise (Throw an exception or set to a well know value) and thus your code work also for situations not planned before.

Of course, when you implement new properties and expect a different behavior of your code, omitting to update this switch will be an easy bug to spot.

Answer (score 1):

> I do one more unnecessary initalization

I also don't like that.

Like manye people have already said, add an extra `default:` section to your `switch` statement. Like this:

```
Control myControl;
switch(x)
{
  case TabType.Edit:
    myControl= ...;
    break;

  case TabType.View:
    myControl= ...;
    break;

  default:
    throw new Exception("Unexpected value of x: " + x);        
 }

 myPageView.Controls.Add(myControl);
```

This is because from your question we understand that you *know* that `x` will always have one of those two values. The compiler doesn't know that. The above code will tell it so.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do one of the two options; either specify the initial value before the `switch`, or add a `default` case so that the compiler knows for sure that the `switch` will initialize the variable.

I would suggest that if the switch doesn't initialize the variable it's possible that you just want to throw an exception.  In that case, just add that code to the `default` case.  That way it's clear in testing when a developer forgets to add the `case` for a new enum value, as opposed to just silently not working.